# On existence of functions in involution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $(M, \omega )$ be a symplectic manifold. A set of functions $f_1, f_2, \dotsc, f_n$ are in involution if $\{f_i, f_j\}= 0$, for all $i$ and $j$,  where $\{f, g\}$ is the Poisson bracket of $f$ and $g$ associated to $\omega$. For any symplectic manifold of dimension $2n$, if there are functions $f_1, f_2, \dotsc, f_n$ such that $(f_1, f_2, \dotsc, f_n)$ defines a Lagrangian fibration then the functions $f_1, f_2, \dotsc, f_n$ are in involution.

Now given a complex manifold $M$ of dimension $n, T^*M$ has a natural symplectic structure $\omega$.

Question: Does $T^*M$ admit a set of $n$ holomorphic functions $f_1, f_2, \dotsc, f_n$, such that $df_1, df_2, \dotsc, df_n$ are linearly independent and the functions are in involution? Or is there any other criterion for existence of such fuctions on $T^*M$?

Comment: You want this to really be a global fibration, no singular fibers? Usually people allow for some kind of singular fibers, but it is tricky to define precisely what a "singular fiber" should be. If no singular fibers, there are homology and homotopy obstructions to being a torus bundle over a torus.

Comment: Generically smooth fibration is enough. Please let me know the references or proof for existence or non-existence of such functions.

Comment: If $M$ is affine, you can use the pullback to $T^*M$ of coordinate functions on $M$.  More generally, the projection from $T^*M$ to $M$ is a Lagrangian fibration.

Comment: I want some fibration with affine base. If we have functions like in question, then they will define such an fibration. so the question is the existence of such functions.

Comment: Embed any real manifold $M$ into Euclidean space. Make the embedding generic so that the first $n=\operatorname{dim} M$ coordinate functions have linearly independent differentials away from some closed subset of measure zero, then follow what Jason Starr says. You really don't use the complex structure at all, and you don't need an affine complex manifold.

Comment: In that case, I think  the functions will not be holomorphic ( not even complex valued functions). Mainly I want a holomorphic map from $T^*M \to \mathbb{C}^n$  such that each fiber is Lagrangian.

Comment: If you want your functions holomorphic, please edit your question to add that condition, which is clearly very strong. .

Comment: Note that $M$ sits inside the cotangent bundle, as the zero section, so if $M$ is compact and connected, then its image in complex Euclidean space will be a point, hence a single Lagrangian fiber.

Comment: Yes. But if such fibration exists then it will induce nonconstant maps on each co-tangent space to the affine space. For example, in the case of moduli space of vector bundles on curves, the Hitchin map has this property.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen for the cotangent bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^1$, which is a desingularization of $\mathbb{C}^2/\pm$?

Comment: There is a morphism from the cotangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^1 $ to $ \mathbb{C}$ which is given by the compositions of $\mathbb{O}(-2) \to \mathbb{O}(-1) \subset \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$. I do not know whether it has the right property. But my question was can we put some conditions on the manifold itself such that the functions satisfy the right property.